# Difficulties in installing Qlik Catalog related SW

Tags: qlikview, qliksense, qlik-expression

I am installing Qlik Catalog SW on Linux Read Hat Enterprise 7.9 following the instructions of the installation guide.

I have got the first problem in Tomcat Installation. Basically, I am not able to connect to Tomcat with the browser.

Below is a detailed list of commands I have used.

I have tried it using Firefox.

When trying to install Chrome I got other issues.

Any hints?

```
*** Installing Chrome ***
# sudo yum install glib
# sudo yum list glibc
# sudo wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm
# sudo yum -y install redhat-lsb libXScrnSaver
# sudo yum -y localinstall google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
Error: Package: google-chrome-stable-95.0.4638.54-1.x86_64 (/google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64)
Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.18)(64bit)
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
*** Installing Tomcat ***
Install wget (if not already installed):
# sudo yum install -y wget
Become the service account user:
# sudo su - qdcuser
Download Apache Tomcat and extract the file in usr/local/qdc:
$ cd /usr/local/qdc
$ wget https://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-9/v9.0.38/bin/apache-tomcat-9.0.38.tar.gz
$ tar -xvf apache-tomcat-9.0.38.tar.gz
Overwrite <tomcat home>/conf/server.xml with the version expanded from the Qlik Catalog zip file:
$ cp /tmp/podium/config/tomcat9-server.xml /usr/local/qdc/apache-tomcat-9.0.38/conf/server.xml
Opening ports 8080 and 8443:
# sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-port=8080/tcp
# sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-port=8443/tcp
# sudo systemctl restart firewalld.service
Setup Apache Tomcat as a service to automatically start when Linux restarts:
# sudo cp /tmp/podium/config/tomcat.service /etc/systemd/system/
# sudo systemctl daemon-reload
# sudo systemctl enable tomcat.service
Edit the file /etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service to insert the correct user and group names:
# sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service
User=qdcuser
Group=qdcgroup
Start Tomcat manually:
$ cd /usr/local/qdc/apache-tomcat-9.0.38
$ ./bin/startup.sh
Browse to the following URL to verify that Tomcat is running:
https://localhost:8443
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
Unable to connect
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at localhost:8443.
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

Answer (score 2):

I too see this issue..   Here is what I think the reason might be..

rpm -qf /usr/lib64/libc.so.6
glibc-2.17-325.el7_9.x86_64

glibc is 2.17 on RHEL 7.9    The developers at google should know this which means it is a bug.

Or.   They should provide that library as part of their package and statically link it.

Short answer.  For now, until Google figures it out and fixes, I might either remove the package, or skip that package.

To skip..

sudo yum -y update --exclude google-chrome-stable*

To remove... Well.. "sudo yum -y remove google-chrome-stable"

Comment: It seems this has been fixed: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1261617

Comment: We install google chrome through our CI pipeline before running our E2E tests and this issue was coming up a few days back but it seems to be fixed for us too.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative until google resolve the problem is:

`sudo yum update --skip-broken`

This can install all updates and ignore chrome